# RA5370STA Wireless Adapter Is Up But Not Working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, wireless-adapter

I've installed the packaged firmware for a RA5370STA based wireless adapter. If I run iwconfig, it shows the ra0 device as up. However, I can't connect to any networks. I'm on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Uhm.. is there anything in "dmesg", or in the logs under /var/log?

Comment: I dunno. A bunch of AsicSwitchChannel, An occasional "SCAN done"